# convert HTML List to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a little problem with my HTML template for convert to JSON. **I wish convert a list of HTML messages to JSON.** Thank you in advance for your response.

**HTML Template**

```
<div class="message">
    <div class="message-data">
        <div class="infos">
            <h4 class="pseudo">Name</h4>
            <span class="date">MM/DD/YYYY</span>
            <span class="time">HH:MM</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="message-content">
        <div class="message-text">
            Message here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Others .message -->
```

**JSON Render**

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            "pseudo": "Name",
            "date": "MM/DD/YYYY",
            "time": "HH:MM",
            "message": "Message here"
        },
        /* ... */
    ]
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far that isn't working?

Comment: If you do some performance tests evaluating the posted solutions please add them as comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

even if it doesn't look that cool I think this will be much faster:

```
var pseudo = document.getElementsByClassName("pseudo");
var date = document.getElementsByClassName("date");
var time = document.getElementsByClassName("time");
var message = document.getElementsByClassName("message-text");

var list = [];
for(var i=0, l=pseudo.length;i<l;i++) {
 list.push({
    pseudo: pseudo[i].textContent,
    data: date[i].textContent,
    time: time[i].textContent,
    message: message[i].textContent
 })
}
console.log(list);
```

.. depending on your file structure this may not be the best solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jQuery` to simply extract your date from `html`:

```js
var result = [];

$(".message").each(function() {
  var obj = {
    pseudo: $(this).find(".pseudo").text(),
    date: $(this).find(".date").text(),
    time: $(this).find(".time").text(),
    message: $(this).find(".message-text").text(),
  };
  result.push(obj);
})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message">
  <div class="message-data">
    <div class="infos">
      <h4 class="pseudo">Name</h4>
      <span class="date">MM/DD/YYYY</span>
      <span class="time">HH:MM</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message-content">
    <div class="message-text">
      Message here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="message">
  <div class="message-data">
    <div class="infos">
      <h4 class="pseudo">John</h4>
      <span class="date">09/11/2011</span>
      <span class="time">HH:MM</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message-content">
    <div class="message-text">
      World Disaster
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply get all your `.message` elements, and cycle through them to add their properties to the resulting Array (I used `trim()` to remove extra spaces at the beginning and the end of the message texts):

```js
console.log( messagesToJSON() );

function messagesToJSON(){
  var messages = [],
      elements = $('.message');
  for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    messages.push({
      "pseudo": elements.eq(i).find('.pseudo').text(),
      "date": elements.eq(i).find('.date').text(),
      "time": elements.eq(i).find('.time').text(),
      "message": elements.eq(i).find('.message-text').text().trim()
    });
  }
  return {list: messages};
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message">
    <div class="message-data">
        <div class="infos">
            <h4 class="pseudo">Kevin</h4>
            <span class="date">08/01/2016</span>
            <span class="time">14:52</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="message-content">
        <div class="message-text">
            Hi there!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="message">
    <div class="message-data">
        <div class="infos">
            <h4 class="pseudo">Robert</h4>
            <span class="date">08/01/2016</span>
            <span class="time">15:03</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="message-content">
        <div class="message-text">
            Hello
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```